# Functional Analysis, Why this statement true?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Why this statement true?

If $f \in C^0([0,1], W^{2,2}(K)) $ then $ f \in C^0 ([0,1] \times K)$.

$ K \subset R^n $ , W : Sobolev Space.

Comment: Is $K$ an arbitrary subset of $\mathbb R^n$? Probably not, otherwise how would you define $W^{2,2}(K)$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is true.  The Sobolev embedding theorem suggests this should only work for small $n$; in this case I think it should be $n < 4$ if I have the parameters right.

To try for a counterexample, let's take, say, $K$ to be the unit ball of $\mathbb{R}^6$, and let $f(t,x) = |x|^t$.  One should be able to show that $$f(t, \cdot), \partial_i f(t, \cdot), \partial_i \partial_j f(t,\cdot)$$
are continuous as functions $[0,1] \to L^2(K)$, which would make $f$ continuous as a map from $[0,1]$ to $W^{2,2}(K)$.  However, as  a function on $[0,1] \times K$, $f$ is clearly not continuous at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Oh then how can I apply Sobolev embedding thm to conclude that n<4 ?

Comment: The [Sobolev embedding theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality) says in this case that for $n < kp$, $W^{k,p}$ is continuously embedded in the Holder space $C^{k - [n/p]-1,\gamma}(K)$ for some $\gamma > 0$, which in turn is continuously embedded in $C(K)$.  (Here $k=p=2$ so we need $n < 4$.)  So in this case if $f \in C([0,1], W^{2,2})$ then $f \in C([0,1], C(K)) = C([0,1] \times K)$.  This isn't a proof that it fails when $n \ge 4$, but I think an example like the one I gave should show it.